# How are energies determined in gamma ray calibration standards?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radioactivity, metrology

In operating scintillation gamma ray detectors, certain gamma ray standards are used for calibration:

```
Energy (KeV)
Na-22, 511
Mn-54, 835
Co-57, 122
```

How are these energies determined.

Comment: Are you asking how we know the Na22 line is 511keV, or asking what mechanism caused that energy to be emitted?

Comment: They may have used some sort of single-crystal x-ray spectrograph to measure the x-ray photon energies. See the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_spectroscopy and the section on "Early history of X-ray spectroscopy in the U.S." in it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [szintillation gamma-ray detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_spectroscopy#Scintillation_detectors)
there are the [semiconductor-based gamma-ray detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_spectroscopy#Semiconductor-based_detectors).
These semiconductor-based detectors (and especially the germanium-based one)
provide a much better energy resolution in comparison to the szintillation detectors.

From [Gamma-ray spectrometer: How a GRS works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_spectrometer#How_a_GRS_works)

> Another approach relies on using Germanium detectors
>    - a crystal of hyperpure germanium
>    that produces pulses proportional to the captured photon energy;
>    while more sensitive, it has to be cooled to a low temperature,
>    requiring a bulky cryogenic apparatus.

Therefore you can calibrate a szintillation detector with the
gamma energies measured with a semiconductor-based detector.

But this immediately raises the next question:
How can a semiconductor-based gamma-ray detector be calibrated?

For low-energy gamma-rays you can measure their
wavelength $\lambda$ from diffraction by crystals.
This is the same method as used for [measuring X-ray wavelengths](https://science.jrank.org/pages/7431/X-Rays-Measuring-x-ray-wavelengths.html)
(see also [Bragg's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/bragg.html)),
because low-energy gamma-rays and high-energy X-rays are essentially
the same thing.
From the wavelength $\lambda$ the energy $E$ of the gamma-photon
can be calculated by $E = h\nu = hc/\lambda$.
However, this method is applicable only if the wavelength is not much smaller
than the atomic distances in the crystal (i.e. for low-energy gamma-rays),
otherwise the diffraction angles would be unmeasurable small.

Comment: But you still haven’t said how the line energies are established, and germanium detectors have nasty nonlinear energy response *especially* in the low energies the OP is asking about.

Comment: @dmckee Good point! I've extended my answer.

Comment: But how is "pulses proportional to the captured photon energy" experimentally verified as a valid relation between voltage output and energy input.

Comment: @itsme This can be verified by checking that the pulses (measured with the gamma photon detector) are proportional to $1/\lambda$ (with $\lambda$ measured with the diffraction method). See the formula $E=hc/\lambda$ in my answer.

Comment: But diffraction method not applicable for some higher energy gamma rays. Then the calibration works only for some lower energy levels. Can we assume extrapolation will also be strictly linear.

Comment: Yes, eventually we are extrapolating here. This is encouraged  by our physical model behind the semiconductor-based detector which predicts this behavior.

Comment: The thing is that germanium detectors in particular *do not* exhibit good linearity in general. Great resolution does not imply good linearity. Calibrating those beasts over any reasonable range of energies is a pain. Been there. Done that. I don't know off hand what detector systems are preferred by metrologists for definitive measurements of line energies, but I am sure it is not Ge detectors.